# No clue of the Georeferencing tool in gvSIG

Tags: georeferencing, gvsig

I have kept trying to locate the georeferencer in gvSIG but I could not find it. Some tutorials say it is under Tools from the main menu!
I installed several versions of gvSIG, both on Windows and Linux but the georeferencer does not appear anywhere. I also tried to install a georeferencing plugin from `http://downloads.gvsig.org/download/gvsig-desktop/pool/org.gvsig.georeferencing/` but after I installed it, the gvSIG won't start.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean [this tool](http://www.gvsig.org/web/projects/gvsig-desktop/docs/user/gvsig-desktop-1-12-manual-de-usuario/gvsig-desktop-1-12-manual-de-usuario-en/gvsig_freemind_toc_view?content=gvSIG%201.11%20User%20manual/Analysis%20and%20data%20processing/Raster/Geographic%20Transformations/Georeferencing)? It is not present yet on gvSIG 2.0 but it's installed by default (AFAIK) on gvSIG 1.12.

You need to have the data on your view to access the user interface of the tool. The buttons work in a little bit strange way, you have to click on the half bottom part of the icon in order to show the menu, as the upper part will fire the selected tool.

Comment: Yes after I installed version 1.12, somehow it worked.
I can say gvSIG has a very hostile environment.